# Angular outputting JSON

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I want to output only the `short_title` from `"id": 28` but I
am unusure how to just call the title from all the JSON and then output
it in Angular within a HTML page.

```
  {
    "content": [
    {
        "id": 29,
        "short_title": "Flow",
        "long_title": "Flow",
        "fields": {
            "images": [
                {
                    "src": "content/29/images/QMTQUZxTMCoJMGrjOeowwqChJmnIe4fmFFT7pSph.jpeg",
                    "title": "Flow_2560.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "type_id": 4,
        "folder_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2017-11-28 16:40:12",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-28 16:40:12",
        "type": {
            "id": 4,
            "code": "image-only",
            "title": "Full screen image",
            "visible_fields": [
                "images"
            ],
            "created_at": "2017-08-31 14:22:59",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-31 14:22:59"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "short_title": "Navigation buttons",
```

I want to just output this short title

```
        "long_title": "Nav buttons 21st November",
        "fields": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "icon": "1",
                    "link": "http://sportspecific.digitaltesting.net/",
                    "size": "full",
                    "title": "Button 1",
                    "bg_colour": "#a64343",
                    "link_type": "url"
                },
                {
                    "icon": "2",
                    "link": "http://sportspecific.digitaltesting.net/",
                    "size": "full",
                    "title": "Button 2",
                    "bg_colour": "#742d2d",
                    "link_type": "url"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].. where how are you showing the data and where are you stuck?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let result1 of data.content">          
                <h1>{{content[1].short_title}}</h1>     
    </div> this is how I am trying to output the data

Answer (score 1):

try `data.content[1].short_title`

in HTML,

`{{data.content[1].short_title}}`

Comment: <div *ngFor="let result1 of data.content">          
                <h1>{{content[1].short_title}}</h1>     
  </div>    I have this but nothing is outputting?

Comment: <h1>{{data.content[1].short_title}}</h1>

Comment: if you are simply going to output one item, you don't need *ngFor. ngFor is for looping through arrays. You can simply output short_title by <h1>{{data.content[1].short_title}}</h1>

Comment: Hi Gowtham, I have tried that now i am getting the uncaught (in promise) type error? loadUser() {
    this.http.get('assets/json/content.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    console.log('this.data', this.data);
    })
    }   That is my function to call the json

Comment: I am getting the error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError Cannot read property 'content'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what index `id: 28` is at, you can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```
let content = data.content.find(item => item.id === 28);
this.shortTitle = content.short_title;
```

Then display it in your html

```
{{shortTitle}}
```

Note: `find` is an es6 function, so you'll need to add a polyfill